# Global Updates With UserDefaults In SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, userdefaults, appstorage

I've been using @AppStorage and UserDefaults for updates in SwiftUI. If I make a change to the vie that has the @AppStorage wrapper all works well. I'm confused with how to make this work globally.

I'm using a struct that has computed properties and formatters associated. The idea is to check user defaults and convert items to lbs or kg. The issue is that the views using the computed properties do not update when UserDefaults is updated. Is there a way to create a global change that would update weightFormatted in SecondaryView below?

// Weight Struct

```
struct Weight {
var weight: Double
var weightFormatted: String {
return weightDecimalLbsOrKgFormatted2(weight)
}
```

// Formatting Method

```
func weightDecimalLbsOrKgFormatted2(_ lbs: Double) -> String {
    if (!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "weightInKilograms")) {
        let weightString = decimalFormatterDecimal2(lbs)
        return weightString + "lbs"
        
    } else {
        let kg = toKg(lbs)
        let weightString = decimalFormatterDecimal2(kg)
        return weightString + "kg"
    }
}
```

// Where weightInKilograms Is Set

```
struct AccountView: View {
    @AppStorage("weightInKilograms") var weightInKilograms = false

    let weight = Weight(weight: 9.0))
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(weight.weightFormatted)
            Toggle(isOn: $weightInKilograms) {
                        Text("Kilograms")
            }
        }
}
}
```

// Secondary View Not Updating

```
struct SecondaryView: View {

    let weight = Weight(weight: 9.0))
    
    var body: some View {
         Text(weight.weightFormatted)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `weight` isn't wrapped by any state.

In your `AccountView`, give `weight` a `@State` wrapper:

```swift
struct AccountView: View {
  
  @AppStorage("weightInKilograms") var weightInKilograms = false
  
  @State var weight = Weight(weight: 9.0))
  
  var body: some View {
    //...
  }
}
```

In `SecondaryView`, ensure that `weight` is wrapped with `@Binding`:

```swift
struct SecondaryView: View {
  
  @Binding var weight: Weight
  
  var body: some View {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then, pass `weight` as a `Binding<Weight>` variable to `SecondaryView` within your first View:

```swift
SecondaryView(weight: $weight)
```

> Is there a way to create a global change that would update weightFormatted in SecondaryView below?

If you're looking to make a *global* change, you should consider setting up a global `EnvironmentObject`:

```swift
class MyGlobalClass: ObservableObject {

  // Published variables will update view states when changed.
  @Published var weightInKilograms: Bool
  { get {
    // Get UserDefaults here
  } set {
    // Set UserDefaults here
  }}

  @Published var weight: Weight
}
```

If you pass an instance of `MyGlobalClass` as an `EnvironmentObject` to your main view, then to your secondary view, any changes made to properties in the global instance will update the views' state via the `@Published` wrapper:

```swift
let global = MyGlobalClass()

/* ... */

// In your app's lifecycle, or where AccountView is instantiated
AccountView().environmentObject(global)
```

```swift
struct AccountView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var global: MyGlobalClass

  var body: some View {
    // ...
    Text(global.weight.weightFormatted)
    // ...
    SecondaryView().environmentObject(global)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply. I’m adding this info and some Combine code to correct this.